# Make the new tag I made into a synonym of an existing tag please

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I just invented the [schengen-d-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schengen-d-visas) tag since I noticed that visas of this type were often enough referred to to warrant a tag of their own.

But as I got to the end of the list of questions with both "visa" and "D" in them, I realized that a previous tag, [long-stay-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/long-stay-visas), already exists for the same job.

Since so many newer questions don't have the old tag that shows it's not obvious to everybody so having both synonyms should make it more discoverable.

So please turn my new tag into a synonym of the old tag.

Or if enough of you go to [the tag synonym page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/long-stay-visas/synonyms) and vote for it as a synonym that ought to have the same effect.

Comment: Check out our meta post on tag edits: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/3278/22140

Comment: @JoErNanO: Yeah I've found over the years that adding to metas like that sometimes don't get noticed after the original was responded to.

Comment: Indeed that can happen. My solution is to regularly ping mods in the chat. :)

Comment: @JoErNanO: It seems to have happened with the `cave` -> `caves` request.

Comment: Is there a way to "ping the mods" generically, without having to investigate who they actually are at any given point in time?

Comment: I wish there were. An @mods would be great, although that's probably what flagging for moderation attention does.

Comment: Oh well let me go do that of course! (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the new synonym for new questions. I did not map existing question tags (presumably the ones you added) to [long-stay-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/long-stay-visas), however.

Comment: Hmm, is that something the system does by itself later on then?

Comment: No. You'll either have to do it manually or be sure that the change is appropriate and let me know. (This sort of retagging is not reversible so I need to be sure it's what you all want.)

Comment: It seems you did just what I wanted and I don't know how to do it manually so I'd say go ahead and do it if you have a one-click way to do so.

Comment: @hippietrail: Done. (Sorry about the run around. I just wanted to be sure.)

Comment: No worries. Mod tools are black magic to me (-: